how to use отметить to mean "to sign out"
I've just noted on Wiktionary that отметить can mean to "sign out, register out". What is the full phrase? I signed out of the hotel? отметил из отеля? I registered out when leaving the conference? я отметил с совещания? I don't think this is right. The Russian version of Wiktionary, викисловарь, doesn't have this meaning -- maybe it is not common. Maybe a noun needs to go in there? Я отметил свой выход из отеля??

"Отметить свой выход (или вход) (в книге посещений, например)" may work. But the word alone doesn't really mean 'sign out'.

I think this entry in Wiktionary is basically misleading.

I also think that Wiktionary is wrong here. "Отметить" means "to mark" or "to note" (or "celebrate", but this is irrelevant now). Only in some very specific cases "to mark/note" may be related to signing out (e.g. if there is some registry for those who sign out), and thus "отметить" might imply signing out, but even then, this is not a meaning of a word, but just an implication.

Отметить (кого-либо) does have a meaning of "check (someone) in or out; punch (someone) in or out".
More often than not it's used in its reflexive form: отметиться ("to check in or out; to punch in or out"), but the transitive form is also sometimes being used:


— Рассаживайтесь, товарищи, и прошу отметиться. Список напечатан, пустите по кругу!
— Да что там! Отмечай, Надя! Отметь меня — цех водно-бревенный! // Север. Россия, Карельское книжное изд-во., 1985.
— Саня, так смотри же, отметь меня на секции. Поняла? Всё, я с ребятами в кино! // Petrunina, Nadezhda. Зимняя черемуха: повести и рассказы. Россия, Московский рабочий, 1986.
— Инночка? Здравствуй, доброе утро! Я тут в пробке застряла. — щебетала Катя в трубку, быстро выдергивая из шкафа дежурные юбку с блузкой. — Да. Отметь меня. Ага. Спасибо, милая, с меня конфетка. // Спаси себя. Россия, SelfPub, 2022.


